# Hive INSERT INTO HBase - Possible key generation?

Tags: hadoop, hive, key, hbase, generator

I've been trying to import a .csv file into HBase through Hive to avoid programming a Bulk Load program in java. I've managed to load the whole .csv (bilions of rows) into Hive, and because I had some issues with Hbase, I was trying to import only the first 10 rows before importing the rest.

The thing is, the .csv file does not have a unique value for each row to assign as the HBase table key required by HBase. This results in INSERT OVERWRITE only inserting the last row of the 10, because the column I originally defined as key contains the same value on all 10 rows (but that's not true across the whole file)

Is there a way for Hive / Hbase to generate a key column with incrementing integers / floats / any other type?

Comment: So you dont want to design row key, and want an auto increment feature from Hbase? But then you loose the cushion provided for faster retrieval when searched with row key. Hope you are aware of it

Comment: @Ramzy I'm investigating row design topics now and I see what you mean, even though I'm new to manipulating Big Data. I think I at least understand how the row key affects performance on reads / writes, even though I don't know how to configure the generation. But right now me and my team just want to test the storage part of our setting, we are far from production matters yet. When we know we can safely store data and read data, we'll investigate performance issues in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I see several solutions:

- hive hbase integration supports composite primary keys
- concat_ws(columns)
- reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID")
- sha1(concat_ws(columns)) #could result in collisions

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-SimpleCompositeRowKeys